# Magento - Limit title length for seo

Tags: magento, seo

I'd really like to limit the title length on products in Magento.

What I've tried is adding `'maxlength' => 65` somewhere in `\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\`, without success.

Does someone know how to add this feature? In HTML it will just be adding `length="65" maxlength="65"`.

Thanks for all affords. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the platform available to give you a proper walkthrough on setting this up, but I should be able to get you in the right place. First of all, do not make changes in the app/code/core files. Any changes you would absolutely need to make to those files you should do by making a copy of lets say app/code/core/Mage/Sales/something.php to app/code/local/Mage/Sales/something.php. Magento knows to automatically use the code in local to override the code in core.

If you take a look at the source code for that page you'll see where the name form is:

```
<input id="name" name="product[name]" value="" class=" required-entry input-text required-entry" type="text"/>            </td>
<td class="scope-label"><span class="nobr">[STORE VIEW]</span></td>
    </tr>
```

What's going on here is you'll notice under class we have "required-entry input-text and, well, required-entry again. These are the validation tags defined in js/prototype/validation.js. You will need to add some custom validation to it, and add it to your template file (not in core, it can break when you upgrade).

You'll notice in validation.js a section

```
Validation.add('IsEmpty', '', function(v) {
```

In this section you can add your custom validation. Lets say:

```
//make sure these are unique, I'm not checking
['validate-length', 'Your input needs to be less than x characters.', function(v) {
    if (v.length > x) return false;
}],
```

If you need help finding the template location, take a look at: [Finding Correct Templates and Blocks in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963284/finding-correct-templates-and-blocks-in-magento). You'll simply add validate-length class such as: class="required-entry validate-length..."

Comment: Templates for rendering attribute inputs are not locked to one attribute. Using the above advice, I think that OP can just add the classname to the `frontend_class ` column for the meta_title attribute in `eav_attribute` after creating a validate-length65 rule as you've suggested.

Comment: Witch file in `\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\ ` do I have to edit to simply add `length="65" maxlength="65"` to the `<input>`-field? Checking afterwards doesn't seem the best option.

Answer (score 0):

After almost 10 hours of searching I gave the up the "best" way, and choose for the roundabout.

Simply add

```
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("maxlength", "65");
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("length", "65");
```

to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/wysiwyg/js.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript validator to the product's `name` attribute. To achieve this, you need to update attribute with special value for frontend class. Just create sql upgrade:

```
$this->updateAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'name',
    array(
        'frontend_class' => 'validate-length maximum-length-65',
        'note'           => 'Max length is 65 characters'
    )
);
```