# Magento create new product template

Tags: php, magento, product, mage

I really like the magento structure but finding things is very hard ;)

My problem is that I have a custom attribute. By calling ‘create new product’ this field should be prefilled with an automatic value like the entity-id. This should only happen within the create new function.

I’m absolutely not capable of finding the corresponding code, where the initial values are set, can anyone give me a hint? (a script must run, not a default value :))

Thanks a lot and grettings,
Matthias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is overwritting the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes block.

Within this block, you can use a simple if condiition. the following line has to be replaced by the if:

```
$values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getDefaultValue();
```

new solution:

```
if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'my_attribute_code') {
    $values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = SET_THE_OWN_VALUE;
} else {
    $values[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getDefaultValue();
}
```

That's all :)

Hope this helps some one else, too !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the information needed to find the corresponding code in this post:
[Finding Correct Templates and Blocks in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963284/finding-correct-templates-and-blocks-in-magento)

Simply change the default attribute of the field to what you need it to be.

Comment: This is a missunderstanding, I want that field in the backend and by creating a new product this should be prefilled - this field will be used for exports and not available within the frontend ...

Comment: That link shows you how to enable template paths for the adminhtml as well. You still edit the template the same way you do the frontend.

Comment: Your tip was not bad, especially for a general overview of the templates ... Thanks a lot!